# Git Remove Directory Syntax

Tags: git, version-control

According to progit book, **$ git rm log/\*.log**   removes all *.log files in log directory. What is the meaning of the backslash "\" here ? The book says this is necessary because git does its own filename expansion in addition to the shell’s filename expansion. could you please specify the meaning ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That isn't a git question, it is a `sh(1)` question.

The answer is that your shell will expand the wildcard `*` by default, and the escape stops that happening, so that the argument to `git rm` is `log/*.log` rather than `log/a.log log/b.log log/c.log` all spelled out.

The practical significance is zero, unless you are removing a logfile that isn't in the working tree, though.